# Change visualforce outputText on MouseOver

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, actionsupport

I need to present a social security number field on a record detail page only when the cursor is over the field.  I'd like the value to be all asterisks and then reveal the SSN on mouse over and then revert to asterisks on mouseOut, but nothing happens

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Financial_Account__c" extensions="hsaFAController">
<apex:outputPanel id = "hsaBlock">
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="HSA Beneficiary" rendered="{!hsa}" >
        <apex:outputField label="Beneficiary" value="{!Financial_Account__c.HSA_Beneficiary__c}"/>
        <apex:outputText label="SSN" value="{!SSN}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onMouseOver" action="{!showSSN}" rerender="hsaBlock"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onMouseOut" action="{!showSSN}" rerender="hsaBlock"/>
        </apex:outputText>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:OutputPanel>
```

Controller extension:

```
public class hsaFAController {
//initialize some
private Financial_Account__c FA;
private final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
public boolean hsa{get;set;}
public string SSN{get;set;}
private final String faID;
public hsaFAController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    this.controller = stdController;
    this.FA = [SELECT id, recordTypeId, alternate_Research_Class__c FROM Financial_Account__c WHERE id = :controller.getId()];
    system.debug(FA);
    ssn = '***********';
    hsa = fa.Alternate_Research_Class__c == 'HSA'?true:false;
}

public pageReference showSSN(){
    ssn = ssn.contains('*')?fa.Beneficiary_SSN__c:'***********';
    return null;
}

public string getSSN(){
    return ssn;
}
}
```

Comment: what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: RIght, I guess that would help, sorry.  Nothing happens on mouseOver or mouseOut.  I'll edit the post

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is **case sensitive**. If you look at [the documentation for the `<apex:actionSupport>` component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm), you will see some of the supported values for `event`:

> The DOM event that generates the AJAX request. Possible values include "onblur", "onchange", "onclick", "ondblclick", "onfocus", "onkeydown", "onkeypress", "onkeyup", "onmousedown", "onmousemove", "onmouseout", "onmouseover", "onmouseup", "onselect", and so on. These values are case sensitive.

**Change `"onMouseOver"` to `"onmouseover"`. Change `"onMouseOut"` to `"onmouseout"`. No upper case.**